# C# WPF connecting to MySql server and create db if doesn't exist

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I'm trying to create new DB if it doesn't exist when pressing the button "Restore" but it keeps jumping to the exception. What am i doing wrong?

```
private void Button_Click_Restore(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string CreateDatabase;
            string dbInfo = "DATABASE=" + Database.Text;
            string connectionString = "SERVER=" + Hostname.Text + ";" + dbInfo + ";" + "UID=" + User.Text + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + Password.Text + ";" + "PORT=" + Port.Text;
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            CreateDatabase = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + Database.Text + " ; ";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(CreateDatabase);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteReader();

                MessageBox.Show("DB has been created.");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Check Server and Database name.");
                
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You hide the actual Exception and then show a generic MessageBox. If you don't look at the Exception you don't now why it is failing.

Comment: Client/Server RDBMs like MySQL, MS SQL, and Postgres are generally not designed for allowing any user to create new databases all the time (unlike with, say, Sqlite or JET). You usually need higher-level permissions to create new databases.